# How to auto increment primary key in Room?

Tags: android, database, class, kotlin, android-room

```
data class FavouriteEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id : Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id") var userId : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fav_restaurant_id") var favouriteRestaurantId : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fav_restaurant_name") var favouriteRestaurantName : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fav_restaurant_img") var favouriteRestaurantImage : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fav_restaurant_price") var favouriteRestaurantPrice : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fav_restaurant_rating") var favouriteRestaurantRating : String
)
```

Above class is my Entity class. I want the primary key to auto increment.
But when I create an object of the class like :

```
var favouriteEntity = FavouriteEntity(

            userId,
            restaurant.restaurantId,
            restaurant.restaurantName,
            restaurant.restaurantImageUrl,
            restaurant.restaurantCostForOne,
            restaurant.restaurantRating
        )
```

I need to pass an integer as the id. But i want to id to auto-increment. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply:

```kotlin
data class FavouriteEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id : Int = 0 
)
```

or

```kotlin
data class FavouriteEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id : Int? = null 
)
```

and the id field will auto-generate/auto-increment the `id` field.

Then use it with named parameters: e.g.

```kotlin
data class FavouriteEntity(
        val id: Int = 0,
        val name: String
)

fun main() {
    FavouriteEntity(name = "name")
}
```

Comment: What value should I assign to id when I create an Object of this class.? If I leave it blank, it shows an error.

Comment: No value. Just use named parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As the id will be autogenerated, you can change your code to:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id : Int = 0
```

This way you can skip setting a value:

```
var favouriteEntity = FavouriteEntity(
            restaurant.restaurantId,
            restaurant.restaurantName,
            restaurant.restaurantImageUrl,
            restaurant.restaurantCostForOne,
            restaurant.restaurantRating
        )
```

Comment: What value should I assign to id when I create an Object of this class.? If I leave it blank, it shows an error.

Comment: You just skip the id value. I have edited my answer to be more clear.